# How to access file from node inside Jenkins shared library script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am calling a shared library groovy script from my Jenkins pipeline.

Using the `pwd()` method I can properly get the workspace path and I can even see the required file in the exact same location in the Jenkins node.

Still I am getting following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Jenkins\workspace\Demo\test\target\site\xyz\abc.csv (No such file or directory)
```

I have the `groovy-scripts/vars/generateHtml.groovy` shared library which is being called from the pipeline as `generateHtml()`. The relevant code snippet:

```
def call() {
  def ws = pwd()
  echo "path ${ws}: generateHtml>start"
  def targetPath = "${ws}\\target\\"
  def resultFile = targetPath + 'site\\xyz\\abc.csv'
  def data = parseCsv(new File(resultFile).getText('UTF-8'))
...
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: @StephenKing relevant code snippet added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a file in Jenkins Pipelines goes via `readFile`. Don't use plain groovy for I/O.